# How do i remove the second occurance of a filename from each row in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm creating a renaming pair file for bulk rename utility in notepad++ so i can rename a lot of files with names like gjpoju908g00s43.mp4 to last christmas.mp4

however i need to delete the second occurance of each filename from each line

an example of what i have

```
yTYPlMhaPta29we2IzR29NXS6dHmFmfm.mp4|2017-03-09random textyTYPlMhaPta29we2IzR29NXS6dHmFmfm.mp4
HPFoZp9Dka8Jh5BRBYHjbRbWHzHQieRQ.mp4|2017-03-09random textHPFoZp9Dka8Jh5BRBYHjbRbWHzHQieRQ.mp4
lMmPri5tmUupVUOYzF2K2UZBVH9O3JY0.mp4|2017-03-09random text\u2764lMmPri5tmUupVUOYzF2K2UZBVH9O3JY0.mp4
td4jRfsNLxSX7w42ErHc5szTQ4SsF72y.mp4|2017-03-08random text!!td4jRfsNLxSX7w42ErHc5szTQ4SsF72y.mp4
O1UJ3bwtkf6yTzYtuLjjJAHH0DciZGv4.mp4|2017-03-04random text.O1UJ3bwtkf6yTzYtuLjjJAHH0DciZGv4.mp4
```

What i would like

```
yTYPlMhaPta29we2IzR29NXS6dHmFmfm.mp4|2017-03-09random text.mp4
HPFoZp9Dka8Jh5BRBYHjbRbWHzHQieRQ.mp4|2017-03-09random text!.mp4
lMmPri5tmUupVUOYzF2K2UZBVH9O3JY0.mp4|2017-03-09random text\u2764l.mp4
td4jRfsNLxSX7w42ErHc5szTQ4SsF72y.mp4|2017-03-08random text!!.mp4
O1UJ3bwtkf6yTzYtuLjjJAHH0DciZGv4.mp4|2017-03-04random text..mp4
```

please note the "random text" part is in place of my actual file names, they're all different, not the actual words "random text" each time. So i basically just want to remove the second occurrence of the filename, that starts a row, from each row.

I'm really new to all of this so i've been doing my best to search and find my own answers and i've already managed to get the file to where it is by figuring out how to delete everything between two characters, creating new lines after certain characters and a few other things that i'm sure are super basic to you all, but this last part i just can not figure out how to do it or if it's even possible.

I know i could just go through and manually select the start of each row, find and replace with blank but there's over 245 rows so i'd rather find an automated way if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?)\.mp4.+?\K\1`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
\.mp4       # literally .mp4
.+?         # 1 or more any character but newline
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\1          # backreference to group 1
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way is:

Find : `^([^.]*)(.*)\1`
Replace by : `\1\2`

Comment: You're assuming there're no dots in the filename.

Comment: @Toto: Yes, I am.